# C Why is the character input It only shows the front body

Tags: c

Why is the character input It only shows the front body in case 1
everyone can help me?
I want it to show more than 1 character.

```
    int  choice, i;
    char item,arr_queue[MAX_SIZE];
    int rear = 0;
    int front = 0;
    int exit = 1;
    printf("\nSimple Queue Example - Array");
    do {
        printf("\n\n Queue Main Menu");
        printf("\n1.Insert \n2.Remove \n3.Display ");
        printf("\nEnter Your Choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                if (rear == MAX_SIZE)
                    printf("\n## Queue Reached Max!!");
                else {
                    printf("\nEnter The Value to be Insert : ");
                    scanf("%s", &item);
                    printf("\n## Position : %d , Insert Value  :  %c ", rear + 1, item);
                    arr_queue[rear++] = item;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (front == rear)
                    printf("\n## Queue is Empty!");
                else {
                    printf("\n## Position : %d , Remove Value  : %c ", front, arr_queue[front]);
                    front++;
                }
                break;
```

Comment: The word 'body' does not appear in your code.  What do you mean with "front body"?  Also, please write what you input and what you expect to see and why.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", &item);` is wrong. `%s` is to read null-terminated strings, and `item` is only a single `char` and can't hold a null-terminated string (well, it *can* hold a zero-length string, but not anything else).

By attempting to read a string, at least two characters will be written to where `&item` is pointing, leading to *undefined behavior*. What is likely to actually happen in your program is that some other local variable gets overwritten and its value is not what's expected.

To read a single character with `scanf` use `scanf(" %c", &item)`. Note the leading space in the format. And remember to always check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).